# NSTableView, didSelectRowAt not being hit

Tags: swift, nstableview

Ive searched for the answer, but the majority of examples ive found here and online are for IOS and im trying for OSX, sorry im not advanced enough to understand the IOS examples ive found online.

I can populate the table, so I know the delegate is working. but didSelectRowAt is not being hit?

here is my code, its from an example i found online and have tried to implement the didSelectRowAt.

```
import Cocoa

struct Task {
    var schedule: String
    var description: String
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!
    
    var items = [Task(schedule: "8:00 - 9:00", description: "Hacer ejercicios"),
                 Task(schedule: "9:00 - 13:00", description: "Trabajar")]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Add this

        self.tableView.reloadData() // RECON THIS LOADS THE DATA TO TABLE
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        

        
    }
}





extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        print("Test")
    }
    
    
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let currentItem = self.items[row]
        
        if tableColumn?.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "scheduleColumn") {
            
            let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "scheduleCell")
            guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {
                return nil
            }
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = currentItem.schedule
            return cellView
            
        } else if tableColumn?.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "descriptionColumn") {
            let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "descriptionCell")
            guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {
                return nil
            }
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = currentItem.description
            return cellView
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

im very new to swift. so please be nice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong delegate method. Try this one:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
        
    print("Selected")
        
    return true
}
```

I assume you were looking at the iOS `UITableView` method [`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }
```

Just changing `UITableView` to `NSTableView` does not work -- by doing that, you just made a new method that is not part of the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol. So, it will never be called.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!.its working as expected. I was looking at the IOS version in the docs as you mentioned, i havent worked out which functions etc are for what yet very confusing but really do appreciate your reply.

Comment: @Lorenzo707 you can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate) for a full list of all the methods included in the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol.